# WCF rest large json error

Tags: json, wcf

I have a WCF rest service using webHttpBinding that returns JSON result. The problem is that I can't return large JSON results. Works great for smaller results, but at about 1.16MB result size, I get empty responce. Fiddler gives me this:

```
HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Timestamp: 15:57:24.251

[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.
```

Chrome gives me 'Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.'

I tried to set every option in binding and readerQuotas section of web.config that starts with 'max' but it did not work. I host the WCF service in IIS but the same thing happens in self-hosted service.

How do I increase max sent JSON result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in your service behavior, try playing around with the `maxItemsInObjectGraph`:

```
<dataContractSerializer ignoreExtensionDataObject="true" maxItemsInObjectGraph="123456" />
```

Comment: It worked!

Thank you and sorry for late reply, I only had time to test it now.

Comment: That's good, I'm happy it worked. Could you set the answer to accepted then? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you I have been struggling with this for an long time and it has caused me a lot of pain. Out of interest why have you set the maxItemsInObjectGraph to "123456" it works but I want to know why it works.

Comment: You can set it to the max size of Int32.MaxValue.  The maximum number of items to serialize or deserialize.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.maxitemsinobjectgraph(v=vs.110).aspx